# javascript, keep button fast clicking~

Tags: javascript

in html, I make a button.
the button should click one time per second.
I do not want to permit fast button clicking~

so my code is here

```
inputTooFast = function()
{
    var curDate = new Date();
    if(curDate.getHours() == this.lastinputtime[0])
        if(curDate.getMinutes() == this.lastinputtime[1])
            if(curDate.getSeconds() == this.lastinputtime[2])
                if((curDate.getMilliseconds() - this.lastinputtime[2]) < 999)
                {
                    this.lastinputtime[0] = curDate.getHours();
                    this.lastinputtime[1] = curDate.getMinutes();
                    this.lastinputtime[2] = curDate.getSeconds();
                    this.lastinputtime[3] = curDate.getMilliseconds();
                    return true;
                }
    this.lastinputtime[0] = curDate.getHours();
    this.lastinputtime[1] = curDate.getMinutes();
    this.lastinputtime[2] = curDate.getSeconds();
    this.lastinputtime[3] = curDate.getMilliseconds();
    return false;
}
```

and sample usage is here

```
function sendMessage()
{
    if(theObj.inputTooFast()==true)
        return;

 ...
   some valid code here
 ...

}
```

so, is there any faster or better solution to do this?
I am using jquery.

Comment: usually, chat send button will use this function~

Comment: no~, I just didn't know how to accept answer. with your question, I found it out~ thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're trying not to provide user feedback that the button can't be clicked. If so, I'd probably do something like this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ozoze4/)) (if not, see below):

```
sendMsg.blocked = 0;
function sendMsg() {
    if (sendMsg.blocked == 0) {
        ++sendMsg.blocked;
        setTimeout(removeSendMsgBlock, 1000); // If you want one second

        // ...other processing
    }
}
function removeSendMsgBlock() {
    --sendMsg.blocked;
}
```

If you want to give the user feedback (usually a good idea), disable the button like this ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ozoze4/3)):

```
btnSendMsg = /* ...get the button element... */;
function sendMsg() {
    btnSendMsg.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(removeSendMsgBlock, 1000); // If you want one second

    // ...other processing
    display("Sending message at " + new Date());
}
function removeSendMsgBlock() {
    btnSendMsg.disabled = false;
}
```

---

**Update**: Actually, there's no need for an extra symbol, just put the remove function reference on the `sendMsg` function object too:

Example 1 reworked:

```
sendMsg.blocked = 0;
function sendMsg() {
    if (sendMsg.blocked == 0) {
        ++sendMsg.blocked;
        setTimeout(sendMsg.removeBlock, 1000); // If you want one second

        // ...other processing
    }
}
sendMsg.removeBlock = function() {
    --sendMsg.blocked;
};
```

Example 2 reworked:

```
btnSendMsg = /* ...get the button element... */;
function sendMsg() {
    btnSendMsg.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(sendMsg.removeBlock, 1000); // If you want one second

    // ...other processing
    display("Sending message at " + new Date());
}
sendMsg.removeBlock = function() {
    btnSendMsg.disabled = false;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to store those fields in an array.  You can store them as a `Date`, or as a `number`, which I've chosen to do here since you are only using it later for numeric comparison:

```
inputTooFast = function() {
    return (new Date()).getTime() - this.lastInputTime < 1000;
}
```

Note that if this returns false, and you continue, you'll need to store `lastInputTime`.